# Can ActiveMQ topics be partitioned such that it uses key in the messages to determine which partition to publish message to?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have application A which publishes messages to ActiveMQ queues q1 and q2 and I have two consumers c1 and c2 connected q1 and q2 separately. The message format for both c1 and c2 are different , thats why I am using two separate queues.

Is it possible to use a single topic with ActiveMQ, which it further partitions into p1 and p2, and have c1 subscribe to p1 and c2 subscribe to p2?
A can uses key in the messages to determine the partition to subscribe to. Is this possible using ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. JMS supports SQL 92 syntax for creating queries that consumers can use to get just the messages they want. See the JMS selector in section 9.1.8 [JMS Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf).

Also, ActiveMQ doc [ActiveMQ Selectors](https://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html)

Also, ActiveMQ server-side routing using selectors and filtered destinations (see section second from the bottom) [Filtered Destinations](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations)